# GUI.DrawTexture and GUITexture multitouch

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a car game for android and I created Throttle, Break and Steering Wheel.

All is working good but I can't use Steering Wheel when I touch throttle or brake. 
Or when I'm using Steering wheel, if I touch to throttle or break, Steering Wheel is a little messing.

Throttle and break are `GUITexture`,
Steering Wheel is using `GUI.DrawTexture` (because GUITexture does not support rotating)

I'm checking touches like this:

```
int touchCount = Input.touchCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < touchCount; ++i){
            Touch t = Input.GetTouch(i);

if (t.phase != TouchPhase.Ended &&
                this.throttleButton.texture.HitTest(t.position)){
                throttle = 1f;

            }

if (t.phase != TouchPhase.Ended &&
                this.brakeButton.texture.HitTest(t.position)){
                brake = 1f; 
            }
       //inputGuiPosition variable was used because Unity3d GUI system is a little opposite

       Vector3 inputGuiPosition = t.position;
       inputGuiPosition.y = Screen.height - inputGuiPosition.y;

       if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began &&
         wheelRect.Contains((inputGuiPosition))){       
         steerInput = SteeringWheel.GetAngle () * (-1f/270f);

            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because Unity's GUI doesn't support multi-touch. You need some input touch controls asset from the unity's asset store if you want multi-touch in your Unity game.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure OnGUI can't handle multi-touch. You should to look at using the touch API instead: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html